# Why won't my CMD batch IF condition work?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In my batch script I have a variable

```
SET VAR=SVI
```

and an IF condition

```
IF "%VAR%"=="SVI" (
   ECHO HELLO
)
```

that doesn't work!

If I say `ECHO IF "%VAR%"=="SVI"` just before the `IF` statement it will output `"SVI"=="SVI"` but it still refuses to go into the statement and output `HELLO`.

What could it be?  I really have no idea!

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: Works for me. Can you post your full code?

Comment: Thank you for your availability.  I cannot post the full code as I am exploring other options as a workaround.  I thought maybe this was a known issue and I was missing something.

Comment: Like I said, the 4 lines of code from your question work for me when I copy & paste them into a batch file. If they don't work with your production code the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Depending on the circumstances, you might need to `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `if "!var!"=="SVI"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have mismatched parens???  Try removing them as you don't need them for your example.
IF "%VAR%"=="SVI" ECHO HELLO
or to do case insensitive check 
IF /I "%VAR%"=="SVI" ECHO HELLO